# Java stream - find unique elements

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have `List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();` and I want to list all unique names. I mean If there are "John", "Max", "John", "Greg" then I want to list only "Max" and "Greg". Is there some way to do it with Java stream?

Comment: Try doing some basic research first: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java%20stream%20unique.

Comment: Stream it collecting into a set :) Actually, just make a set if you don't care about the order.

Comment: Any code attempt on your side?

Comment: @9000 using a set won't help because he wants `John` off the results because it has a dup!

Comment: @alfasin: Then distinct won't help either. The right way would be to reduce it to a map of pairs (name, count) and then filter those with count == 1.

Comment: @9000 did I say that distinct will help ?????

Comment: @alfasin: you did not; the first commenter did.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can use streams and `Collectors.groupingBy` in order to count how many occurrences we have of each name - then filter any name that appears more than once:

```
    List<String> res = persons.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
            .map(e -> e.getKey())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(res); // [Max, Greg]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
List persons = new ArrayList();
    persons.add("Max");
    persons.add("John");
    persons.add("John");
    persons.add("Greg");

    persons.stream()
             .filter(person -> Collections.frequency(persons, person) == 1)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: In case element is object inside list, then object should override equals and hashcode method to make frequency work.

Comment: this solution takes only elements frequency once not unique (*without duplicates*)

Comment: `Collections.frequency` iterates all the list for each element of the stream, to find the number of occurrences, so it's `O(n^2)`, which is extremely inefficient

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution:

```
List<String> persons = new ArrayList<>();
persons.add("John");
persons.add("John");
persons.add("MAX");
persons.add("Greg");
persons.stream()
          .distinct()
          .sorted()
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: downvoted because it does not answer the question (leaves John in the result)

Answer (score 5):

First guess solution.

```
persons.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
       .entrySet()
       .stream()
       .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == 1)
       .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
       .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post, but I'd like to propose yet another approach based on a custom collector:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> excludingDuplicates() {
    return Collector.<T, Map<T, Boolean>, List<T>>of(
        LinkedHashMap::new,
        (map, elem) -> map.compute(elem, (k, v) -> v == null),
        (left, right) -> {
            right.forEach((k, v) -> left.merge(k, v, (o, n) -> false));
            return left;
        },
        m -> m.keySet().stream().filter(m::get).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Here I'm using [`Collector.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-) to create a custom collector that will accumulate elements on a `LinkedHashMap`: if the element is not present as a key, its value will be `true`, otherwise it will be `false`. The merge function is only applied for parallel streams and it merges the `right` map into the `left` map by attempting to put each entry of the `right` map in the `left` map, changing the value of already present keys to `false`. Finally, the finisher function returns a list with the keys of the map whose values are `true`.

This method can be used as follows:

```
List<String> people = Arrays.asList("John", "Max", "John", "Greg");

List<String> result = people.stream().collect(excludingDuplicates());

System.out.println(result); // [Max, Greg]
```

---

And here's another approach simpler than using a custom collector:

```
Map<String, Boolean> duplicates = new LinkedHashMap<>();
people.forEach(elem -> duplicates.compute(elem, (k, v) -> v != null));
duplicates.values().removeIf(v -> v);

Set<String> allUnique = duplicates.keySet();

System.out.println(allUnique); // [Max, Greg]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below code.

```
    List<Person> uniquePersons = personList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(person -> person.getName()))
            .entrySet().stream().filter(stringListEntry -> stringListEntry.getValue().size()==1)
            .map(stringListEntry -> { return stringListEntry.getValue().get(0); })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

This should remove all the duplicate elements.

```
List<String> persons = new ArrayList<>();

        persons.add("John");
        persons.add("John");
        persons.add("MAX");
        persons.add("Greg");

        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

        Set<String> duplicateSet = new HashSet<String>();

        for (String p : persons) {

            if (!set.add(p)) {
                duplicateSet.add(p);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(duplicateSet.toString());
        set.removeAll(duplicateSet);
        System.out.println(set.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply **use `Collections.frequency` to check the element occurance in the list** as shown below to filter the duplicates:

```
List<String> listInputs = new ArrayList<>();
//add your users
List<String> listOutputs = new ArrayList<>();
for(String value : listInputs) {
     if(Collections.frequency(listInputs, value) ==1) {
         listOutputs.add(value);
     }
}
System.out.println(listOutputs);
```